# What should be checked to play video correctly: density or screen size?

Tags: android, video, resolution, screen-size

Please excuse me if you think this is a stupid question for I don't know what I should do now.

I have a video file with 1024 x 576 resolution. I tried to play it on a HTC Hero GSM device and it doesn't play. I then tried to play it on Samsung Galaxy Tab and some China made tablet and it plays well. So, I resized the video to 480 x 270 and it works well on HTC. But the video is of bad quality. That's why I decided to make two videos, for tablet and Hero-like devices.

This is the problem. Of the devices I tested, HTC Hero is normal-screen and mdpi, Galaxy tab is large-screen and hdpi. With this, I don't know if the 1024x576 video doesn't play on Hero because of its normal screen or because of its density. Same also for the galaxy tab.

I ask now, what could be the reason for the Hero to not play 1024x576 video? Is it because it has small screen or because it is mdpi?

I ask this because there are devices that are normal screen but hdpi. And I would like to load the 1024 x 576 video with this kind of device.

I hope you understand my problem.
Thanks in advance.